# Silverlight validation message location

Tags: silverlight, validation, exception

While using the default validation handling in Silverlight ( using ValidatesOnExceptions=True,NotifyOnValidationError=True),
you typically get the exception message towards the side the textbox. 

I would like the change the location of the validation message (exception message) and put it on the top of textbox. Any ideas on how I can do it. I could not find any literature on changing the error message location on the net.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is (IMO) a sad oversight in the default validation UI.  There should be a way for you to specify the ToolTip placement value, instead the placement value is fixed in the template to be "Right".

Hence to change this you need to visit this MSDN topic [Textbox Styles and Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645061%28v=VS.95%29.aspx), make a copy of the `TextBox` default style and the referenced "ValidationToolTipTemplate".  Add these to a fresh `ResourceDictionary` file and give the `TextBox` `Style` a Key value.  You can now adjust the validation tooltip `Placement` property in the text box template.

Include this new `ResourceDictionary` as merged dictionary in either your App.Xaml or your UserControl/Page resources and assign this style to your `TextBox` `Style` property.

Excessive mucking about for just a simple change but there is no other way.  On the upside you can do all sorts of other things with the text box style and/or the Validation tooltip now that you have them in your own code.

Comment: If anything, I feel this sort of thing is more a oversight in Visual Studio's designer.  Making this sort of change is much more straightforward in Expression Blend.  Right click on the object template->edit a copy and you get the whole template to edit.

Comment: @Brandorf:  If VS did everything that Blend could how would MS get to sell Expression?  ;)

Comment: Thanks Anthony.. My problem is solved. I have uploaded the silverlight view at https://gist.github.com/1276226 for anybody looking for help regarding this issue.